# T-SQL Finding VarChar String with Wildcards, but Carriage Return in Field Produces Fewer Results

Tags: sql, string, wildcard, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to find all rows with a specific variable character alpha-numeric string from a variable character field using the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table AS t
WHERE t.Textfield LIKE '%abc123abc%' OR t.Textfield LIKE '%aabbcc12345abcde%';
```

However, not all of the rows are being returned. I figured out that the rows which were not being returned from my query aren't showing up because of a carriage return after the final character of the alpha-numeric string I'm looking for.

My question is what can I do to make sure all of the rows return for my query instead of just the rows not having a carriage return at the end of my variable character alpha-numeric string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would strip out those characters in a subquery.

```
SELECT *
    FROM ( 
    select 
        rtrim(ltrim(replace(replace(TextField,char(10),''), char(13),''))) as TextField
         ) AS t
WHERE 
    t.Textfield LIKE '%abc123abc%' 
    OR t.Textfield LIKE '%aabbcc12345abcde%';
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/22/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-insert-carriage-return-and-new-line-feed-in-code/